# What does the return of the mods mean?

Tags: discussion

Does it mean they’ve determined no change or correction is forthcoming from SE about Monica’s ejection and this is just the new normal?  And there’s nothing to be gained by continuing to object?  Or what?  What led to this decision?  Is there anything the community would benefit from knowing about the situation?

Comment: I think it means they're honouring their commitments and showing that their overriding loyalty is to the people who voted them the diamonds in the first place. Which is this community, not Monica or SE, we voted them in. I see it as a positive

Comment: I think they support what comes from S E.

Comment: "Return of the Mods" sounds like the sequel to a horror film. :)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere sequel between The Mods Conspiracy, and Revenge of the Mods....

Comment: Not all of us have returned. I fully respect Snow's and Mister Positive's decision to return and the reasons why, but after spending the weekend with my family and time to think, my decision remains at this stage. Nothing has changed in SE's stance nor their treatment of Monica, so at least for now, neither does mine.

Comment: @JaneS no worries, enjoy your family time

Comment: Who is Monica and why do we care so much about her?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper

Comment: @David The short summary is that there were a mixture of topics with hateful opinions and miscommunication, plus combination of Jewish holidays and a firing of a mod that triggered an avalanche of perspectives. Well, the even shorter version is a sh!tstorm happened and a **LOT** of mods resigned. Some of them decided to come back.

Answer (score 27):

I detailed my inner conflicts and thoughts in my messages in the Water Cooler yesterday. I quote them here. Basically, kilisi is correct in saying that while I don’t agree with SE at all, I value The Workplace. Me returning doesn’t validate SE’s action.

> After yet another sleepless night of tossing and turning and stealing all of the bedsheets, I can't take any more. I'm in conflict about how much I value this (Workplace) community and how little I value SE as a company and how it handles it's volunteers. That conflict has been roaring around in my head for weeks now (and stress makes my tinnitus worse). It's affected my relationship with my partner.
>
> Stepping away isn't the  answer for me, I have emotional ties to this place. I value supporting this community, I value the other users (you guys) supporting it. It pains me that it's being left and no one is sweeping up the leaves and chopping out the deadwood.
>
> At around 2am this morning, I reached a resolution inside myself. I determined to not give in to this continuing conflict and let it eat me up. I have therefore formally asked to be reinstated as a moderator here to serve this community that I value more than SE appears to value me (as a moderator).
>
> For full disclosure, this is the email I sent.
>
> "I am requesting reinstatement as a moderator of The Workplace.
>
> As much as I disagree with the manner in which Monica was removed, and multiple resignations/strikes have pressed home that the community at large was also not happy, I still value the community that the web site serves.
>
> As much as in good conscience I could not serve a company that did this, I cannot in good conscience let this community unmoderated.

I hope this answers your question. For ready up on the wider issues, please refer to main meta.

Thanks again for supporting The Workplace.

Comment: Certainly was. There’s no easy path out of this mess. However, recovery has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 26):

It means that two individuals thought things over and concluded that it would be better for them to be moderators than not to be moderators.

They each have their own personal reasons which we should respect, just as we should respect the reasons of those who chose to no longer be moderators.

Nothing more.

I fully support those who have chosen to return to moderator status. And I fully support those who chose not to return. I thank all of the current and former moderators for trying to make The Workplace a good place to be.

I am happy to do whatever I can to help any of them in any way I can - all they have to do is ask.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  This pretty much sums up my path thus far.